# Which character to use for getting the first place in file listing?

Tags: windows, linux, mac

Our colleagues are competing first place in file listing on shared folder, e.g., ls -1 /mnt

```
 ZFirstplace
!YSecond
!!ZThird
123
2012-08-23 14.19.35.jpg
2012-08-23 14.19.38.jpg
```

Use access the folder in various operation systems via samba and most of the has ascending alphabetical order as default.  Is there character to gain the first place from the space character?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like basic lexicological(alphabetical++) order, which means it goes according to the [ASCII](http://www.jimprice.com/ascii-0-127.gif) table.

Space appears to be the first normal character of the list though.

Answer (score 0):

You could try (but it may cause problems, at least of display, and at worst in some software) to create it using this way: to type the name: first press ALT down, and then the ascii code (001 is the first you shuold try, as 000 is probably off limit), then unpress ALT. This will create the corresopnding ascii character.  ex:

```
[ALT-and-stay-pressed]001["unpress-alt"]rest_of_the_name_here
```